# how to make button align horizontally using css style

Tags: c#, css, model-view-controller, styles

This is how mine looks like

[image: 1]

I want it like this

[image: 2]

the first picture, it always happened when the there are many column in a table (eg: having 8 column per table) while the second picture only having like 5 column per table

i've tried using vertical - top but i might have done something wrong. both button also having different class.

Comment: What library are using for the table? Is the icon buttons column auto-generated by the library? Give more information.

Comment: Can you share the codes for those buttons?

Answer (score 0):

Make a div and wrap the two icons and give some class then add this CSS to that div,

```css
.that_div_class {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}
```

After this, you can give other CSS to the two icons as you wish.

Answer (score 0):

To ensure that the action column's icons are horizontally aligned, set a minimum width for the column. This will prevent the icons from being separated from each other horizontally.

Example for using Bootstrap:

```html
<table class="table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th scope="col">Name</th>
      <th scope="col" style="min-width: 150px;">Action</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
...
</table>
```